# Как подключить два варианта толщины шрифта

Tags: html, css

У меня есть ссылка на шрифт:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;600&display=swap');
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
</style>
```

Для заголовков мне нужна толщина шрифта 600, а для текста 300.

Comment: Вы хотите разную толщину для заголовка и для текста?

Comment: в целом да, но, где толщина 300 там еще у шрифта преписка light, меня она только смущает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать так:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;600&display=swap');
h1 {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 600;
}

p {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec magna augue, imperdiet vitae lectus ut, luctus convallis nibh. Ut ligula lacus, mattis sit amet ipsum eget, posuere auctor ligula. Curabitur sodales tincidunt venenatis. Ut id semper tortor.
  Nam non facilisis neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent non vehicula nibh. Duis augue mi, blandit sed elit sed, venenatis interdum turpis. Proin quis odio quis metus vehicula elementum quis at nisi. Vivamus ut purus non felis elementum pretium.
  Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent non sem in risus sodales mollis. Donec efficitur sit amet dui quis tristique. Vestibulum in urna fermentum elit maximus pellentesque ornare id erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque fermentum odio vitae ligula tempor congue.</p>
```

Предписка light это всего лишь буквенное обозначение, тобишь можно написать: `font-weight: light;`, но это плохой стандарт кода, тоже самое как `color: red;`, лучше всегда писать численнные значения.